# Django - Queryset Dataframe - turn decimals into floats

Tags: python, django, list, django-queryset

I am turning a queryset into a dataframe.
The thing is that the type of the items are 'Decimals' (for instance: Decimal('-1800000.00') ) . I would like these to turn into normal floats so I can make computations with them.

How can I do this?

Thanks to all !!

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(list(Item.objects.filter(item__slug=fundslug).values('date','amount')))
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `.astype("float")`

Either as

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame([Item.objects.filter(
                                   item__slug=fundslug).values(
                                       'date','amount')]).astype("float")
```

or

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame([Item.objects.filter(
                                   item__slug=fundslug).values(
                                       'date','amount').astype("float")])
```

It should do the same thing either way.

Pandas holds its values as numpy arrays by default, so unless `.values('date','amount')` is specifying the exact values you want from your method call in some way, you probably don't need it.

Also, if you're only returning the date and amount it's better to declare it as a DateTime rather than a float as it wil probably save you computational time later on. I'd also recommend making the date the [index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.html).

Comment: hi Puhtooi :) ok thanks but Iget the following error:: TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict' ? how can I resolve this

Comment: `Item.objects.filter(item__slug=fundslug)` Must be returning a Dict. So you need a way to index that dict. I'd look into breaking this up into more than one line of code, or really dive into what that method call is doing. You're solution looks elegant, it seems what it's doing is more complex than a one liner.

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame(list(qs), columns=fields).astype("float")
I have error in other string fields. Can you advise?